# How to recover bad namenode from good namenode

Tags: linux, hdfs, ambari, hdp, namenode

I want to share all , about how to recover second bad `namenode` when using the good `namenode`

- example of one bad `namenode` and one good `namenode`

[image]

So for this scenario lets say the following

*The bad namenode is on machine hadoop1
The good namenode is on machine  hadoop2*

As all know the following folders are the most important folders on the namenode machines

```
/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current

/var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current
```

So the question is:

How to recover the bad namenode when using the folders - `/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current` , `/var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current` ?

For example , can we do the following ?

On bad namenode ( `hadoop1 machine` )

Stop all `namenode` services ( include journal nodes and zookeeper fail over )

```
mv  /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current   /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current_bad

mv /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current_bad



mkdir /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current   

mkdir /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current



chown hdfs:Hadoop /hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current   

chown hdfs:Hadoop /var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current
```

copy the content of the good n`amenode` folders `/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current`   to bad `namenode`  -  `/hadoop/hdfs/journal/hdfsha/current`

copy the content of the good `namenode`  `/var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current` to bad `namenode`  -  `/var/hadoop/hdfs/namenode/current`

start all `HDFS` service as namenode , journal nodes , zookeeper fail over

is this scenario can recover the bad `namenode` ? ,

***NOTE - if some steps are missing then please share any info about this***